# Store Javascript values in an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have this javascript code:

```
var allVals = [];
$('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
   allVals.push($(this).val());
});
alert(allVals + "is checked!");
```

The code above, will list all the checked values from checkboxes like this: **value,value,value**

How can I, when submitting my form, store those values in a PHP array, so I can use them?

Comment: When you submit a form, if a box is not checked it's value won't be sent. So you really don't need that js code above.

Maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Brian: That's a _non sequitur_; the JS code above doesn't do anything about sending anything.

Answer (score 1):

Name all your checkboxes "`c_b[]`".

The values of those that are checked will then be accessible in the target PHP script as the array `$_POST['c_b']` (or `$_GET['c_b']`).

---

This is covered fairly well in [the relevant manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php), and [the manual's FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) (oh, the irony!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use array's `join` method to get all the array values as a combined string and then pass it along with the form while submitting it as a hidden field. At the Php side you can split this string and then convert it into an array.

```
var strAllVals = allVals.join(',');
```

Comment: A hilarious way to send "arrays" to a form target!

Answer (score 0):

Make all your checkboxes name to 1 name.

Then PHP will have the values in an array.

Btw if you re using jquery AJAX you could use serializeArray()